# EmberJS Template concatenate

Tags: templates, ember.js, handlebars.js

How can I can concatenate strings( or how to add classes ) on templates on EmberJs?

ex.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
// This div I want to add a class go, Is this the right way to do it?
<div class="fly {{isGo}}">Fly now</div>

// Or it's something like this?
<div class="fly "{{isGo}} >Fly now</div>
</script>
```

Comment: This is well documented in the [guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-class-names/)

Comment: http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-class-names/

Answer (score 2):

`bind-attr` used to be a good way of working around a limitation within Ember's rendering. Now with HTMLbars Ember has recommend that we move away from `bind-attr` as we have more powerful methods.

> Ember 1.13 deprecated bind-attr in favor of the new syntax.
>   http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_bind-attr

Working example of the two proposed methods can be seen in action on ember twiddle ,here:
https://ember-twiddle.com/38f69f01d2fd994af3b0965f10882005?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C

## Method 1

If you want to do the combination inside your handlebars template you could do something like:

```
<div class={{concat "fly " isGo}}>Fly now</div>
```

## Method 2

otherwise use a computed property like:

```
  flyingClass: Ember.computed('isGo', function() {
    // return a string with 'fly' and the value of
    // isGo. Will be updated if isGo changes.
    // Array values are created with space delimited by
    // ['className', 'anotherClassName', 'lastClastName'].join(' ');
    // => "className anotherClassName lastClassName"
    let going = this.get('isGo') ? 'going' : ''
    return ['fly', going].join(' ');
  })
```

and then in your handlebars template:

```
<div class={{flyingClass}}>Fly now</div>
```

The main difference between the two methods depends on how you want your separation of concerns. Right now it might be easier to just do Method 1, but as conditions get more complicated you could hide more of the work in the computed property.

Answer (score 1):

There is a complete discussion of this in the Ember guide: http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-class-names/

But you'd do it like this:

```
<div {{bind-attr class="isGo"}}>Fly now</div>
```

And in your controller:

```
App.MyController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    flightIsAGo: true,
    isGo: function() {
        return "fly"+this.get('flightIsAGo') ? ' isGo' : '';
    }.property('flightIsAGo')
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I see, I have to bind it in a controller, but I'm just wondering' about this 'export default', is this a valid expression?

Comment: Sorry, that is ES6 format, in traditional JavaScript you would use `App.ThingController = Ember.ObjectController.extend...` etc.  I have changed the answer.

Comment: I would also advise  this http://emberjs.com/guides/views/customizing-a-views-element/